# Looping through a column and returning value

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, if-statement, na

I want to loop through one of the columns in my data frame and check a condition, then replace 0 or 1. The code is  :

```
for (i in v$R){
     if( is.na(v$R) ==TRUE ){v$V5 = 0}else{v$V5=1}
}
```

But I get an error. The data frame named 'v' is as follow. The V5 has NA values and I want to replace with 0 if values in R columns are NA, and else replace with 1. How can I do that?

```
A B R V5
1 2 3 NA
4 5 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can try `ifelse` like below

```
df <- within(df,V5 <- ifelse(is.na(R),0,1))
```

or `+` (which converts logical value to numerical ones)

```
df <- within(df,V5 <- +!is.na(R))
```

such that

```
> df
  A B  R V5
1 1 2  3  1
2 4 5 NA  0
```

- If you would like to use loops, you can try

```
for (i in seq_along(df$R)){
  if( is.na(df$R[i]) ==TRUE ){df$V5[i] = 0}else{df$V5[i]=1}
}
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L), B = c(2L, 5L), R = c(3L, NA), V5 = c(NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @R_mad you are welcome. I also added the `for` loop answer. If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it. thanks!

Comment: I want to check if values are belong to a column or not, then return a value of 0 or 1 to another column which has NA values by default. could you please look at my code below:
for (i in seq_along(df)){
            if( i %in% df$x ){df$V5[i] = 0}else{df$V5[i]=1}
      } @ThomasIsCoding

Comment: @R_mad Could you create another post for your question, I cannot fully understand the new question if you don't provide some example or expected result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
v$V5 <- ifelse(is.na(v$R), 0, 1)
```